# Do not wait for full WAR deployment

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, jenkins

I am new one in jenkins, linux and tomcat so i need your advice.

Is that possible to configure tomcat in way, not to wait for full WAR deployment?

E.x. new WAR file deployed to webapps/ and started to deploy automatically, so Jenkins waits for full app WAR deployment.
I just need to let Jenkins know, that app started to deploy and do not wait until it fully deploys.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by configuring Tomcat to not wait for full war deployment? Tomcat will not be able to run the application until the war is fully deployed. Are you using any _plugin_ for deploying war?

Comment: Yes, i am using:

<artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
version>2.5</version>
<goals>deploy</deploy>

Comment: What exactly do you mean by configuring Tomcat to not wait for full war deployment? Is the war deployment code present in Maven? Is it ok if the steps after war deployment happens in parallel with war deployment? Is that what you query is?

Comment: I will specify. Is that possible to exclude "Deploying" step?

[INFO] [INFO] cargo-maven2-plugin:1.4.4:redeploy (default-cli) @ gos-webapp 
..
[INFO] [mcat7xRemoteDeployer] Redeploying [/export/storage0/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/workspace/gos-parent/releases/dev-mm-ru/gos-webapp/target/gus.war]
[INFO] [mcat7xRemoteDeployer] Undeploying [/export/storage0/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/workspace/gos-parent/releases/dev-mm-ru/gos-webapp/target/gus.war]
[INFO] [mcat7xRemoteDeployer] Deploying [/export/storage0/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/workspace/gos-parent/releases/dev-mm-ru/gos-webapp/target/gus.war]

Comment: This looks like log output to me. From where do you want to exclude it? From log or do you want to skip this step altogether? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, that was piece of log from catalina.out. I want to exclude deploying step from webapp pom.xml in maven cargo plugin, it must not execute. Simply keep Redeploying and Undeploying steps.

Comment: Webapp pom.xml:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
  <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.4</version>
  <configuration>
   <container>
   <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
   <type>remote</type>
   </container>
   <configuration>
   <type>runtime</type>
   <properties>
  <cargo.remote.username>${deployment.tomcat.username}</cargo.remote.username>
<cargo.remote.password>${deployment.tomcat.password}</cargo.remote.password>
<cargo.remote.uri>${deployment.tomcat.uri}</cargo.remote.uri>
    </properties>
    </configuration>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>

Comment: Your above code does not contain anything related to deployment. Also, what do you want Jenkins to do?

Comment: With Jenkins - nothing, i just monitor and make builds there.
I have inserted this into cargo maven plugin, but my build anyway fail in Deploying step, but i just want to skip it, only lefting Redeploying and Undeploying steps:
...
<configuration>
...
<executions>
   <execution>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <configuration>
              <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
   </execution>
</executions>
</configuration>